# OL3 / Geoserver: Vector tile labels gets cropped

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I am trying to label vector tile point features but they always gets cropped at the tile border. I have tried (among many other things) using the renderBuffer option with no success.
I am using OL 3.19 and the vector tiles are served with Geoserver 2.10RC1 and I get the same errors in my production environment as well as editing an Boundless example (http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/vectortiles/index.html).

I think maybe the tiles are served correctly from Geoserver and that Openlayers somehow render and then slices the tiles before presentation but I am kind of stuck on this.

Any ideas?

[Screenshot of the way it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2JdR.png)

And the code snippet:

```js
 <script>
  var style_simple = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: '#ADD8E6'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#880000',
      width: 1
    }),
 text: new ol.style.Text({
 text:'LOREMIPSUM'})
  });

  function simpleStyle(feature) {
    return style_simple;
  }
  
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
  center: [0,0],
  zoom: 4
    }),
    layers: [new ol.layer.VectorTile({
 renderBuffer:50, //doesn't matter
      style:simpleStyle,
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        tilePixelRatio: 1,
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/testlayer@EPSG%3A3857@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
      })
    })]
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: The `renderBuffer` option won't help. Like suggested in the answer below, your tiles need to repeat the label points on neighbouring tiles.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with `ol.layer.VectorTile` and text labels.
All labels are sliced on the tile boundaries.

[image]
Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/rn3qc4ca/

I asked the openlayers developers for help: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/6275
-> This is not a bug in openlayers. The mapbox tiles really repeat the label points in neighbored tiles. If you use very big fonts the label will still be cropped.

---

My (unimplemented) idea is to place all labels into a separate `ol.layer.Vector` layer. As this type of layer is not sliced into tiles it is always printed completely.

Comment: Thats really strange since in the OL3 example (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles-advanced.html) the labels looks great.

Comment: The Mapbox tiles in that example repeat labels on neighbouring tiles. This is why they look great there.